# No signature of method: CSVFormat.withDelimiter() is applicable for argument types: [;]?

Tags: java, csv, groovy

I want to parse a CSV file using the Apache commons CSV parser but groovy throws an exception when passing the delimiter ';' as char, because groovy passes a java.lang.Character and the method expects a primitive char. 
i use groovy in my unit test, java 7.

**Any body know how to solve this issue?**

```
//Create the CSVFormat object
  CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader().withDelimiter(';');

  //initialize the CSVParser object
  CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(new FileReader(filePath), format);


groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:    org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat.withDelimiter() is applicable for argument  types: (java.lang.String) values: [,]
 Possible solutions: withDelimiter(char), getDelimiter()
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at test.ca.azb.j2ee.obb3.TestPersistence.testLoadHyrCsvToHyrTable(TestPersistence.groovy:226)
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Groovy is passing a `String`.

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:    org.apache.commonsormat.withDelimiter() is applicable for argument  types: (java.lang.String)...

`';'` is a String, but you can [turn it into a character](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_characters):

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader().withDelimiter(';' as char)
```

`';' as char` will actually produce a `java.lang.Character` but Groovy will unwrap it for you to produce the `char` required by the method.